# os.getenv returns empty list in function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a notepad app and wanted to add features like save-open files however i get an empty tuple when i print the codes on line 54-62

i tried to check if os.getenv("home") alone was returning an empty tuple but it worked normally and returned my home directory

https://github.com/MrYasin/Notepad---/blob/master/Notepad.py

If i try to save or open a file i get a 
FileNotFoundError:[Errno 2] No such file or directory:''